# Default gems used by rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to rails.I was just doing Bundle install and noticed that there are a lot of gems which are required by Rails to start.

I just want to know if there is a list of default Gems which the rails installs everytime.

I know it sounds a bit odd but I wanted to know about it.

Comment: Did you installed the RubyGem package

Comment: You can see the list of default gems in Gemfile and all list of gems which are dependent of default gems are listed in Gemfile.lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Ruby gem is plugin that enchances the features and functionality of the Ruby programming language. The following is a list of the pre-installed Ruby gems:

```
actionmailer (1.2.1) - Service layer for easy email delivery and testing
actionpack (1.12.1) - Web-flow and rendering framework putting the VC in MVC
actionwebservice (1.1.2) - Web service support for Action Pack
activerecord (1.14.2) - Implements the ActiveRecord pattern for ORM
activesupport (1.3.1) - Support and utility classes used by the Rails framework
fcgi (0.8.6.1) - The fcgi gem facilitates FastCGI, which we use in concert with mod_fastcgi to accelerate your Ruby on Rails applications
gruff (0.1.2) - A library for making graphs
mysql (2.7)/pg - The MySQL/PG Ruby gem allows you to connect to and use MySQL/PG databases. We fully support MySQL/PG and the Ruby bindings to it.
rails (1.1.2) - The Ruby on Rails package
rake (0.7.1) - Ruby based make-like utility, required by many Ruby applications and gems.
rmagick (1.10.1) - RMagick allows you to use the ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick libraries, similar to GD support in PHP or Perl.
```

Also

```
gem 'carrierwave'

gem 'devise'
```

Answer (score 3):

I understand your confusion, so let me explain it. By default your Gemfile requires only a few gems, rails among them. But you see dozens of gems installed on a fresh `bundle install`.
The thing is that gems usually depend on other gems, and they, in turn can depend on other gems. As an example, go to rubygems.org and look for `rails` gem. There you'll see the dependencies of this gem. By going to each dependent gem you'll see their respective dependencies.

Bundler builds a data structure when creating a full list of gems to work with, this data structure is called a dependency graph. Once it has this data structure, it creates a Gemfile.lock - a special snapshot dependency file that contains *all* the gems required by your application.

Comment: @PeeVee : You have to search / take those gems which are helpful to build your application. Remove rest of the useless gem. Some gems have dependencies on other. So you should be aware before removing any gem.

Answer (score 1):

After you run bundle install, a Gemfile.lock file will be generated.

The Gemfile.lock contains a list of all the gems that are being used in the application, including all the dependencies.